# how to convert string 'Jan 23 2016 10:30:08AM' or string '23/01/2016 10:30:08' to epoch time in python?

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-comparison

I want to compare 2 times including dates.
for example :
'Jan 23 2016 4:16:09PM' and 'Jan 24 2016 9:43:44PM'

i think the easiest and best way is to convert it in epoch and compare. (Please let me know if there is any other approach better than this)

i tried this :

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
import datetime

timer = 'Jan 23 2016 10:30:08AM'
d = parse(timer).strftime('%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S')

>>> d
'2016,01,23,10,30,08'
```

but it as it is a string, i am not able to pass this value datetime.datetime(d)
i tried to strip() as well. but din't work.

```
datetime.datetime(d.strip())

TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Parse already returns `datetime` object. `.strftime` converts datetime object to a string, hence it doesn't work.
2. `datetime` objects are already comparable, you don't have to convert them to epoch:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> d1 = parse("Jan 23 2016 4:16:09PM")
>>> d2 = parse("Jan 24 2016 9:43:44PM")
>>> d1
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 23, 16, 16, 9)
>>> d2
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 24, 21, 43, 44)
>>> d1 > d2
False
>>> d1 == d2
False
>>> d1 < d2
True
```

Comment: Thanks @h4z3 how do i convert ("Jan 23 2016 4:16:09PM") to (2016, 1, 23, 16, 16, 9)?
i mean i can split, but how to convert 4PM  to 16, without making it a string?

Comment: Read my answer once again. It's not `(2016, 1, 23, 16, 16, 9)`, it's a `datetime` object with those insides. And `parse` function you used does that by itself already!

Comment: ohh, sorry my bad. Thanks a lot.